# Display settings freezes computer

Tags: windows-10, freeze, display-settings

When I right-click on my desktop, then click *Display settings*, an empty settings window appear and my computer is frozen, hard reboot required.

I tried updating the graphics card and my Dell Display Link drivers, and even tried to roll them back.  Nothing changes.

Anything else I should try?

My computer is a Dell Laptop with Windows 10, with 3 monitors hooked on a DellDisplayLink box.

Comment: Eventually, one windows update has almost fixed the problem, but I made a Reset Computert to fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issue resolved after patch and reset.

Comment: A solution that does not require resetting the computer would be nice though.

Comment: However, being able to diagnose the issue requires there to still be an issue. Once the issue has been resolved it become very difficult to verify any proposed solution that may be easier unless we can find a way to recreate the issue.